# NextJS 13 access children props from layout

Tags: next.js

I switched my blog to NextJS 13, using new folder structure, so moved from _app.js and _document.js to the single layout.js, and want access childrens' data from the parent root layout

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {  
    const { title, description } = children.props
    console.log(children.props)
    return <>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <title>{title}</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                {children}
            </body>
        </html>
    </>
}
```

But, in console I see: "undefined".

Is there a way to access childrens' data without fetching it in both layout and page in NextJS 13.

Comment: React uses a parent-to-child data flow so the whole point of `children` is that you don't know what's in it. Also, this layout looks more like the `_document` file in Next so I'd double check you're doing the right thing first.

Comment: It worked flawlessly in 12.x version, I fetched the blog post in children with all metadata, and used that metadata in the parent layout component. Now, in version 13 _document, _app and layout are the same things, I merged the code in one layout.js file. But as getStaicProps in the children page was replaced with getData, I can't figure out how to use this data in the parent layout.

Comment: try to `console.log(children.props)`
you will see that the props are in `children.props.childProp`

Comment: I've tried to implement something like this https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fetching with dummy json object returned by fetchData, but got the same result: childProp: {props: {}} - empty object

Comment: _"Is there a way to access childrens' data without fetching it in both layout and page in NextJS 13"_ - It's fine to fetch data in both, Next.js caches the data so it doesn't need to be re-fetched on subsequent calls. See https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fundamentals#caching-data.

Comment: I know that. The question was how to avoid writing the same logic in two places. For now, I worked around it by moving my head title where I need metadata from the template to a separate head.js file, but it forced me to include this custom head component in each article. I'll wait for appDir to become out of the beta if didn't find what I've asked about, post this as a solution.