# Nextjs 13: query title of page in layout

Tags: typescript, next.js

How can I access the title exported in `metadata` in `layout.tsx`?

`page.tsx`:

```
import { Metadata } from 'next';
 
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Next.js',
};
 
export default function Page() {
  return '...';
}
```

`layout.tsx`:

```
import { ReactNode } from "react";

export default function Layout({children} : {children: ReactNode}) {
    return <>
             <h1>{/*metadata.title <-- what to put here?*/}</h1>
             {children}
           <>
}
```

What should `metadata.title` be replaced with to get the title of the page?
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74306762/nextjs-13-access-children-props-from-layout) seems to be similar, also querying the title of the page, but doesn't have any satisfactory answers.

Answer (score 0):

const segments = useSelectedLayoutSegments();

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-selected-layout-segments

It's probably not the solution you want, but I've at least handled this in the same way as above.

Of course, we redefined the title we needed as a conditional statement for each segment

Comment: URL segments are unrelated to the Metadata such as the title that the OP is going after.